# Dependency Injection using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, nsubstitute

I have got a service class that has a constructor injection that takes IAppConfig. IAppConfig has couple of properties with just getters. And I would like to create an instance of this service class in my test project.

My Service class

```
IAppConfig _appConfig;
public class PeopleService(IAppConfig appConfig)
{
   _appConfig = appConfig;
}
```

AppConfig Interface

```
public interface IAppConfig
{
   string BaseURL {get;}
   string AnotherProperty {get;}
}
```

How do I use NSubstitute to mock the IAppConfig to create an instance of PeopleService.

I have tried the below code, but the properties that I set are empty string.

```
var _appConfig = Substitute.For<IAppConfig>();
_appConfig.BaseURL.Returns("http://localhost");
new PeopleService(_appConfig);
```

But the property set in the _appConfig is not working. I appreciate if someone can help me.

Comment: the properties used in the docs do have `{ get; set; }` so maybe it doesn't work, because there's a setter missing?

Comment: Its a readonly property, which means we donot have a public setter. But we should be able to set it from within the class. I have done that in the actual implementation of interface

Comment: Of course, I understand that. My suggestion was to just try adding a `set;` and see if it works. Who knows, It may not be supported.

Comment: @LibinJoseph Explain what you mean by not working. show what is expected and what is actually happening. Saying it is not working does not tell us anything to be able to help you.

Comment: Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what you need, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: @Nkosi good point. what is returned by `_appConfig.BaseURL`?

Comment: @LuckyLikey : I have tried the setter and that does not work, still the same

Comment: `PeopleService`, `PersonService`, `public class PeopleService(IAppConfig appConfig)`, Help us to help you. The provided code is inconsistent.

Comment: @Nkosi: I think I have added everything that involved in the problem context. I basically wants to create a Mock Object of IAppConfig that I can pass into an instance of PeopleService class. And IAppConfig contains just 2 string properties with getters only.

Comment: @LibinJoseph recheck the question. If you were the person trying to help the creater of this question, where would you start? The provided code would not even compile and there is no path for us to even try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: How is it not working? What are you doing that is not working. It is not clear in the shown code.

Comment: I get you, but when I read the question again it makes sense to me, probably because I know the exact problem. Will be helpful if you could suggest what sort of information should I add further. Happy to do so

Comment: @LibinJoseph Ok cool. Show the current test that you say is not working (all the code). explaining what you want to happen and what is actually happening. That should give a clearer picture of the problem so we can suggest solutions.

Comment: Okay. WHat I mean by not working is that the property that has been filled with value in the test project, does not hold the value. When I step over to the next line of code while debug. Both the properties in the _appConfig have empty values. To be more specific _appConfig.BaseURL does not have the value http://localhost

Comment: can you show us the code, where the value(s) is / are read?

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for helping. I will need to look into who can i summarize the code without loosing the details. I understand what I have shared is an oversimplified example. I will rewrite one and get back to you guys

Comment: @LibinJoseph No worries. Tag us when you do so we can take a look at it. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

Showing this since this is too much to put in a comment.

This simplified example shows that the framework works as expected and that you need to clarify your actual issue better.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass {
    [TestMethod]
    public void NSubstitute_Mocking_ReadOnly_Properties_Works() {
        //Arrange
        var expected = "http://localhost";
        var _appConfig = Substitute.For<IAppConfig>();
        _appConfig.BaseURL.Returns(expected);
        var subject = new PeopleService(_appConfig);

        //Act
        var actual = subject.URL;

        //Assert
        actual.Should().Be(expected);
    }
}

class PeopleService {
    IAppConfig _appConfig;
    public PeopleService(IAppConfig appConfig) {
        _appConfig = appConfig;
    }
    public string URL => _appConfig.BaseURL;
}

public interface IAppConfig {
    string BaseURL { get; }
    string AnotherProperty { get; }
}
```

The above example passed when tested.

Comment: @LibinJoseph this is meant by [mre]. Use this or a similar approach to show us whats bothering you.